# Python: ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures is not running my function in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run an Optical Flow algorithm with multiprocessing using ProcessPoolExecutor() in Python. I need the function "ComputeDenseFlow()" to run in parallel in 4 processes. The relevant part of the code:

```
#computes optical flow between two image frames (gray and prevgray)
def ComputeDenseFlow(gray, prevgray, FlowMethod="Farneback", resx=720, resy=576):
    if FlowMethod=="Farneback":
        flow = cv.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, gray, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
    elif FlowMethod=="DTVL1":
        optical_flow = cv.optflow.DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create(lambda_=0.15, theta=0.25, nscales=3, warps=4, epsilon=0.06)
        flow = optical_flow.calc(prevgray,gray, None)
    return flow

#reads frame from camera
_ret, img = cam.read()

#resizes frame
resized=cv.resize(img,(resx,resy),interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

#makes image black and white
gray = cv.cvtColor(resized, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#splits current and previous images in 4 to process each in parallel
graylist = SplitIn4(gray,resx,resy)
prevgraylist = SplitIn4(prevgray,resx,resy)

#processes 4 image parts in parallel, returns optical flow
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
   flows=executor.map(ComputeDenseFlow, graylist, prevgraylist)
```

The problem is that ComputeDenseFlow() takes around 0.2 seconds without ProcessPoolExecutor, but takes 2 seconds with it. I added some lines to determine whether the processes were actually running in parallel and I don't think they are, as its waiting for a task to end before starting the next one:

```
INF[2.105050167]: function starts running in process [56888]-called-from-process [55686]
INF[2.136220542]: function done running in process[56888]-called-from-process[55686]
INF[2.075246458]: function starts running in process [56889]-called-from-process [55686]
INF[2.125046208]: function done running in process[56889]-called-from-process[55686]
INF[2.129472167]: function starts running in process [56882]-called-from-process [55686]
INF[2.175840042]: function done running in process[56882]-called-from-process[55686]
INF[2.182825834]: function starts running in process [56882]-called-from-process [55686]
INF[2.219143042]: function done running in process[56882]-called-from-process[55686]
```

Why is ProcessPoolExecutor not generating 4 processes in parallel and instead running my function sequentially?

Comment: It has to *spin-up* each of those processes and pass the data to them - that takes time. How many sets of data are there in `(graylist, prevgraylist)`?

Comment: Try it with 100 data sets and specify a chunksize - to see if the overhead is worth it.

Comment: There are only 4 images (arrays, basically) in graylist and 4 in prevgraylist, all 360x288. I tried specifying the chunksize, didnt solve the issue. The issue is that the processes arent running in parallel at all, its waiting for the tasks to end before it starts the next one. I tried it with ThreadPoolExecutor and it seems to work, running the threads in parallel and giving me a ~2x speedup, but in theory ProcessPoolExecutor should be faster (if it was working) as these tasks should be cpu bound

Comment: What are those initial numbers in your debug output, are those timestamps of some sort?

Comment: Those are supposed to be counters of the time it takes to run each of the 4 threads, but they are wrong i think - it takes ~2 seconds to run the function 4 times. (Because its running sequentially and not in parallel, + the time it takes to spin-up each process)

Comment: If those are timestamps, note that the timestamps are printing out of order, meaning you can't count on the order in the output telling you what order they're running in. To check that, I would add `time.sleep(5)` or similar to `ComputeDenseFlow()`.

Comment: I meant, to experiment with more datasets, 25 each of your four arrays, to *see* if ProcessPoolExecutor is giving you an advantage.  If the function takes nominally 200 milliseconds and you map it to 100 arrays does the whole evolution take 200 seconds (sequential execution) or less?